# Is the IPv6 case sensitive

Tags: ipv6

Are the **IPv6** addresses **case sensitive** ?

> 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:b5:9ca5:a266:e068

vs

> 2001:0:5EF5:79FB:B5:9CA5:A266:E068

I'm guessing they are both correct but I need to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IPv6 Address represents hexadecimal digits, which in it's turn is just a bunch of numbers so no, it is **not** case sensitive.

Comment: You shouldn't neglect the fact that an hexadecimal number is represented also with letters [a-f][A-F], so the lower-uppercase representation is a relevant aspect, despite an hexadecimal number being just a number. See [Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27510980/2436175)

Comment: Sure, it is imprecise and visualized at the top given it's "accepted" status. Old answers don't have a special status for which they shouldn't be downvoted, people come here to look for answers all the time, as I did :).

Comment: Then you have a lot more semi-outdated answers to downvote... The IPV6 addresses in OPs post are the same, because the addresses represent just numbers. Then it's always best to follow recommendations about casing but IMHO that's a separate question.

Comment: But 4.3 of rfc5952 says:  The characters "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", and "f" in an IPv6 address
   MUST be represented in lowercase.

Answer (score 36):

Technically, an IPv6 address is case-insensitive, but [RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation, Section 4.3 Lowercase](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.3) says:

```
The characters "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", and "f" in an IPv6 address
MUST be represented in lowercase.
```

Comment: I like the "source of truth" approach to this answer.
No ambiguity when you have an RFC standing beside your answer.   :-)

Comment: I expect Postel's law applies here "Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others". i.e. always emit lower case but accept receipt of either case.

Answer (score 6):

The hexadecimal digits are not case-sensitive, but IETF recommendations suggest the use of lower case letters. IETF are the Internet Engineering Task Force which pretty much regulate how IP addresses are used.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIPv6_address&ei=wVGQVKC5KM3TgwTwj4DoBw&usg=AFQjCNFb_sueXDeBWOdL2mKI1t0HlnIqkA&sig2=GOrnmwINjpqBwt13bmlFSw&bvm=bv.81828268,d.eXY), the hexadecimal digits from an IPv6 address are **case-insensitive**, so yes, *2001:0:5ef5:79fb:b5:9ca5:a266:e068* is the same thing as *2001:0:5EF5:79FB:B5:9CA5:A266:E068*.

Comment: Hahahah yeah, my comment formatting taken too long :/

Comment: Unfortunately, Wikipedia can be edited by anyone to display anything, so not a great "source of truth"...

Answer (score 2):

An IPv6 address is a group of hexadecimal numbers, so it doesn't matter.